# How to group the elements of a list to form a new list

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I am receiving data from my API like this:

```
[
  {grade: "Grade A", id: 1, ifsGrade: "A1XX", ifsType: "01XX", points: 22, type: "Type_1"},
  {grade: "Grade B", id: 2, ifsGrade: "B1XX", ifsType: "02XX", points: 15, type: "Type_1"},
  {grade: "Grade C", id: 3, ifsGrade: "C1XX", ifsType: "03XX", points: 1,  type: "Type_1"},
  {grade: "Grade A", id: 4, ifsGrade: "A2XX", ifsType: "04XX", points: 23, type: "Type_2"},
  {grade: "Grade B", id: 5, ifsGrade: "B2XX", ifsType: "05XX", points: 26, type: "Type_2"}
]
```

Thanks to a StackOverflow post, I managed to transform my list to group each item by type like this:

```js
var API_DATA = [
  {grade: "Grade A", id: 1, ifsGrade: "A1XX", ifsType: "01XX", points: 22, type: "Type_1"},
  {grade: "Grade B", id: 2, ifsGrade: "B1XX", ifsType: "02XX", points: 15, type: "Type_1"},
  {grade: "Grade C", id: 3, ifsGrade: "C1XX", ifsType: "03XX", points: 1,  type: "Type_1"},
  {grade: "Grade A", id: 4, ifsGrade: "A2XX", ifsType: "04XX", points: 23, type: "Type_2"},
  {grade: "Grade B", id: 5, ifsGrade: "B2XX", ifsType: "05XX", points: 26, type: "Type_2"}
];

Array.prototype.groupBy = function(k) {
      return this.reduce((acc, item) => ((acc[item[k]] = [...(acc[item[k]] || []), item]), acc),{});
};

TABLE_DATA = API_DATA.groupBy("type")
console.log(TABLE_DATA)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use this result in a dataSource of an angular material `mat-table` because it is not a list:

```
Error: Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource
```

How can I retrieve a list consisting of several lists:

```
[
  [
    {grade: "Grade A", id: 1, ifsGrade: "A1XX", ifsType: "01XX", points: 22, type: "Type_1"},
    {grade: "Grade B", id: 2, ifsGrade: "B1XX", ifsType: "02XX", points: 15, type: "Type_1"},
    {grade: "Grade C", id: 3, ifsGrade: "C1XX", ifsType: "03XX", points: 1,  type: "Type_1"}
  ],
  [
    {grade: "Grade A", id: 4, ifsGrade: "A2XX", ifsType: "04XX", points: 23, type: "Type_2"},
    {grade: "Grade B", id: 5, ifsGrade: "B2XX", ifsType: "05XX", points: 26, type: "Type_2"}
  ]
]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `TABLE_DATA = API_DATA.reduce((c, a) => {
c[a[0]['type']] = a;
return c;
}, {});`?

Comment: please share code in component  data you get and assing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the values form the object.

```js
Array.prototype.groupBy = function(k) {
    return this.reduce((acc, item) => (acc[item[k]] = [...(acc[item[k]] || []), item], acc), {});
};

var API_DATA = [{ grade: "Grade A", id: 1, ifsGrade: "A1XX", ifsType: "01XX", points: 22, type: "Type_1" }, { grade: "Grade B", id: 2, ifsGrade: "B1XX", ifsType: "02XX", points: 15, type: "Type_1" }, { grade: "Grade C", id: 3, ifsGrade: "C1XX", ifsType: "03XX", points: 1,  type: "Type_1" }, { grade: "Grade A", id: 4, ifsGrade: "A2XX", ifsType: "04XX", points: 23, type: "Type_2" }, { grade: "Grade B", id: 5, ifsGrade: "B2XX", ifsType: "05XX", points: 26, type: "Type_2" }],
    TABLE_DATA = Object.values(API_DATA.groupBy("type"));

console.log(TABLE_DATA);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**UPDATE 2023**

With new standard [`Object.groupBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy):

```js
const
    API_DATA = [{ grade: "Grade A", id: 1, ifsGrade: "A1XX", ifsType: "01XX", points: 22, type: "Type_1" }, { grade: "Grade B", id: 2, ifsGrade: "B1XX", ifsType: "02XX", points: 15, type: "Type_1" }, { grade: "Grade C", id: 3, ifsGrade: "C1XX", ifsType: "03XX", points: 1,  type: "Type_1" }, { grade: "Grade A", id: 4, ifsGrade: "A2XX", ifsType: "04XX", points: 23, type: "Type_2" }, { grade: "Grade B", id: 5, ifsGrade: "B2XX", ifsType: "05XX", points: 26, type: "Type_2" }],
    TABLE_DATA = Object.values(Object.groupBy(API_DATA, ({ type }) => type));

console.log(TABLE_DATA);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer that's what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

You can group this data by two ways.

- First way is grouping to `object`
- Second way is grouping to `array`

**Demo**

> NOTE: I'm using `JSON.stringify(group, null, 2)`. to just prettify the output.

```js
const API_DATA = [
    { grade: "Grade A", id: 1, ifsGrade: "A1XX", ifsType: "01XX", points: 22, type: "Type_1" },
    { grade: "Grade B", id: 2, ifsGrade: "B1XX", ifsType: "02XX", points: 15, type: "Type_1" },
    { grade: "Grade C", id: 3, ifsGrade: "C1XX", ifsType: "03XX", points: 1, type: "Type_1" },
    { grade: "Grade A", id: 4, ifsGrade: "A2XX", ifsType: "04XX", points: 23, type: "Type_2" },
    { grade: "Grade B", id: 5, ifsGrade: "B2XX", ifsType: "05XX", points: 26, type: "Type_2" }
];

const groupBy = 'type';

console.log('------------------');
console.log('------Object------');
console.log('------------------');

const group1 = {};
for (let i = 0; i < API_DATA.length; i++) {
    const element = API_DATA[i];
    const groupByValue = element[groupBy];

    if (typeof group1[groupByValue] === 'undefined') {
        group1[groupByValue] = [element];
    } else {
        group1[groupByValue].push(element);
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(group1, null, 2))




console.log('-------------------');
console.log('-------Array-------');
console.log('-------------------');

const group2 = [];
const tmp = {};
for (let i = 0; i < API_DATA.length; i++) {
    const element = API_DATA[i];
    const groupByValue = element[groupBy];

    if (typeof tmp[groupByValue] === 'undefined') {
        const position = group2.length; // get new position
        tmp[groupByValue] = position; // save it
        group2[position] = [element];
    } else {
        const position = tmp[groupByValue];
        group2[position].push(element);
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(group2, null, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Array.prototype.groupBy = function (k) {
      return this.reduce(
        (acc, item) => ((acc[item[k]] = [...(acc[item[k]] || []), item]), acc),
        []
      );
    };
```

Comment: This returns an empty list

Comment: Why? It is returning a list like [ Type_1: [ { grade: 'Grade A', ....}]]

Comment: No, you can test in a snippet that returns an empty list

Comment: Yes, but if you run this code in the browser or on the server it will be works. I don't know why a shippet returns an empty array

Answer (score 0):

you can use [_.groupBy()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy)  function on [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

```js
var jsonArray = [
  {grade: "Grade A", id: 1, ifsGrade: "A1XX", ifsType: "01XX", points: 22, type: "Type_1"},
  {grade: "Grade B", id: 2, ifsGrade: "B1XX", ifsType: "02XX", points: 15, type: "Type_1"},
  {grade: "Grade C", id: 3, ifsGrade: "C1XX", ifsType: "03XX", points: 1,  type: "Type_1"},
  {grade: "Grade A", id: 4, ifsGrade: "A2XX", ifsType: "04XX", points: 23, type: "Type_2"},
  {grade: "Grade B", id: 5, ifsGrade: "B2XX", ifsType: "05XX", points: 26, type: "Type_2"}
]


var groupJson= _.groupBy(jsonArray, function(jsonArray) {
  return jsonArray.type;
});

console.log(groupJson);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.2/lodash.min.js'></script>
```